Pagination is broken after Joomla 5.2.2 update
Hope, all are doing well.
Let me provide explanation of the pagination issue I am facing:
SEF URL: https://mysite.com/authored/206
Non-SEF URL: https://mysite.com/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&Itemid=2096&authorid=206&layout=author&view=category

The pagination link was looking like before update (https://mysite.com/authored/206?start=2), after update it looks like (https://mysite.com/authored?start=2)
After updating Joomla to version 5.2.2, the pagination functionality broke. Based on my understanding, it seems that the SEF system is unable to fetch the authorid parameter from the Non-SEF URL.
Could you please advise on how to resolve this issue? Hope i explained my issue well.

Your issue might be related to the Joomla 5.1.3 update that fixed a possible Cache Poisoning in Pagination, see the release notes: https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5910-joomla-5-1-3-and-4-4-7-security-and-bug-fix-release.html
The Joomla 5.1.3 FAQ explains the background: https://docs.joomla.org/J5.x:Pagination_class_removes_query_parameters
Are you using the latest version of com_flexicontent?
If you are, maybe you could contact the developer about this issue, show them the FAQ and ask them to implement the "setAdditionalUrlParam" method in their component.

Thank you for your response; it was helpful. However, I have a concern:
Should I make changes directly to the core Joomla files, or is there another way to register additional parameters in the pagination?

The issue is not in the Joomla core files but in com_flexicontent. Editing Joomla or 3rd party core files is not wise. So called "core hacks" can make software unreliable, Furthermore a future update might overwrite your changes. I would contact the developers of com_flexicontent instead. And/or contribute your fix to their github repocitory.
